# Where to put a concrete server if all the modules will use it?

Tags: c#, prism, mef

All the time, in my `INFRASTRUCTURE` module set the interfaces which work as service. And each module create a concrete class of that service.

But this time, I need a service which will have to use all the modules

In infrastructure I have:

```
public interface IApplicationMenuRegistry
{
    void RegisterMenuItem(string menuItemName, string description, Type viewType);
}
```

Each moduleInit receive this interface, and it registers a menu item.

Where should I have to create the concrete service `ApplicationMenuRegistry`? In Infrastructure? Or in another module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most correct answer will be: "it depends". Sometimes you should create the concrete service in the "infrastructure", sometimes somewhere else. But I would suggest you to look at the [DI frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), there are a [lot of different .NET implementations](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx). Let DI framework care about providing `IApplicationMenuRegistry` implementation to the target objects.

Comment: I'm using MEF Container as DI. So you're telling that I must configure it from the bootstrapper?

Comment: @DarfZon Yes, why not. Of course the container should be configured before its first usage, but when exactly - it is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

As ie. said - it depends. Ideally - I think it should be in separate module, and you should use [Module dependencies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921124%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) to specify that all modules depend on one "startup" module. Or, you can somehow initalize first your "shared" module in bootstrapper, and initialize all other modules only after that. "Academic way" is "module dependencies", but real life is always more complicated ;)